# How to create AppEngine Key object with assigned namespace with Java API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, key

I would like to create an AppEngine [`Key`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key)-object that is assigned to a given [namespace](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy). The Python API provides a corresponding parameter in the [`Key.from_path(...)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path)-method, but none of the methods in the Java API's [`KeyFactory`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory) mention namespaces anywhere.

Is my only way to do this to use [`NamespaceManager.set(...)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/NamespaceManager#set%28java.lang.String%29) before I call the constructor of the key?

Or could I work some magic with [`Entities.createNamespaceKey(...)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entities#createNamespaceKey%28java.lang.String%29)? Maybe using the result of that as the parent when I create my actual `Key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `Entities.createNamespaceKey(...)` to create a namespace-aware Key (i.e. to switch namespaces). This method is a helper method when using [namespace metadata queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Java_Namespace_queries).

So the only way is to switch namespaces via `NamespaceManager.set(...)`.